# Adding a column to a DataFrame and combining them

Tags: python, dataframe

I have created four DataFrames and then I added a column to them and then combined them into a single data frame but NaN appeares in the values of the column that I've added
this is the code of adding the period column

```
 bldg_2009_10_df['Period']="2009-10"
bldg_2010_11_df['Period']="2010-11"
bldg_2011_12_df['period']="2011-12"
bldg_2012_13_df['Period']="2012-13"
```

and here I have combined them into a single DataFrame

```
concat_inner_mydf=pd.concat([bldg_2009_10_df,bldg_2010_11_df,bldg_2011_12_df,bldg_2012_13_df])
concat_inner_mydf
```

Comment: Can you provide any sample data?

Comment: most likely the columns you have the different dataframes are different. when concating them, you append the data as rows, and the columns which doesn't contain data will have NaNs